# The number of possible values for $a+b+c+d$ which satisfy $a < b$, $c < d$, $ab = 70$, and $cd = 72$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the natural numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, which satisfy $a < b$, $c < d$, $ab = 70$, and $cd = 72$. The number of possible values for $a+b+c+d$ is ...

We know that the number of positive factors of $70$ is $8$, so for $a < b$, $(a,b)$ there are $4$ possibilities. The number of positive factors of $72$ is $12$, so for $c < d$, $(c,d)$ there are $6$ possibilities.

$4 × 6 = 24$

But when I list them, when $(a,b,c,d) = (2,35,6,12)$ and $(7,10,2,36)$, both have the same sum which is $55$, so the number of possible values for $a+b+c+d$ is $23$.
How can I know the correct answer without listing them?

Comment: sigh. draw a 4 by 6 rectangle, the four rows are the $a+b$ sums, the six columns are the $c+d$ sums. Then you fill in the 24 open squares. Apparently these is some duplication.

Comment: @WillJagy I have, but I want find the answer by calculating, not listing